# Mild language processing of csv file in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, csv, nlp

I'm looking more suggestions on an approach to processing lines of text using specific searches of words or phrases (predictable to me) to transfer into a csv. So for example lines like this:

A south China-based trading firm offered a cargo of low-volatile coking coal on a 15% basis with November laycan at $167/t.
A Hong Kong based trading firm received an offer of mid-volatile coking coal 24% basis with early November delivery at $145/t.

would become delimited info like: 
South China trader, seller, low-volatile, 15%, November, laycan, $167
Hong Kong trader, buyer, mid-volatile, 24%, early November, delivery, $145

There are existing javascript answers to start me suggesting str.split("\n") to set up array. But after that... what coding approach would you recommend to looking for word/phrase matches within a line and then setting up a corresponding comma delimited line of the distilled info (to go into a spreadsheet).

I am an editor looking to speed up data entry, so that's why I have a more general approach question. All the search parameters I can struggle with if I know how to get there. At work we already use javascript to pull in files. People say python is easy but I'd like something easier to use in a Windows at work. I have been google searching my way to an approach without success... just a framework and I can get there.

Answer (score 0):

When you're talking about phrases, it means, you have to analyse the text.

One API that handles multiples languages, including Chinese, that I can recommend, is: http://nlp.linguasys.com